# What is T_Echo and T_Print

Tags: php, printing, echo

There's alot of questions asking for help troubleshooting errors when T_Echo and T_Print arise, but what does the T_ mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stands for "token". PHP source code is split into tokens, then interpreted. This process is known as [tokenization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization).

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) for a list of PHP tokens.

You can see for yourself how tokenization works by running [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) on a piece of PHP code.

The reason why these often come up in basic troubleshooting questions is that the OP has made a syntax error, and the parser encounters an unexpected token as a result of that.